# Razor string variable use as html table th or td title value

Tags: c#, html, variables, razor, title

In a *.cshtml file,

```
@{
var tooltip = "Once a day";
}
<table>
<tr>
    <th title=@tooltip>A</th>
    <th title="Once a day">B</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

The first cell shows only "Once" but the second one shows "Once a day" correctly.
I want to use the same variable in many place. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put quotes around `@tooltip`, you should look at the generated HTML for correctness.

I suspect it would look something similar to

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th title=Once a day>A</th>
    <th title="Once a day">B</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Daebarkee Can you make it as answered?